# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException on Console.CursorLeft = X

Tags: c#, exception, console, outofrangeexception

I got this `Exception` and I really don't understand why.

My Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SomeColors
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int currentCursorX = Console.CursorLeft;
        public static int currentCursorY = Console.CursorTop;

        public static Color color = new Color();

         public static void SetCursorXPosition(int xPosition)
         {
             currentCursorX = xPosition;
             Console.CursorLeft = currentCursorX; // System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException 
         }
        public static void DrawRightHalfCircle(int height,int width,char printedCharacter)
        {
            for (int i = 0;i < height / 2;i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(printedCharacter);
                SetCursorXPosition(currentCursorX + 1);
            }
            SetCursorXPosition(currentCursorX - 1);
            for (int i = 0;i < height / 2;i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(printedCharacter);
                SetCursorXPosition(currentCursorX - 1);
            }
        }        

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const char PRINTED_CHARACTER = '*';
            const ConsoleColor WHITE = ConsoleColor.White;

            color.SetColor(WHITE);

            DrawRightHalfCircle(4, 4, PRINTED_CHARACTER);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

I get the `Exception` on the last iteration of the loop on the `Console.CursorLeft = currentCursorX;` line.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the value of `currentCursorX` at that point? It's likely `null` or `< 0`

Comment: What is the value of the `currentCusorX` when you get the error?

Comment: I don't think post "shows research effort" - there is no [MCVE] for exact problem (which should be `Console.CursorLeft = -1;`). Also code shows lack of good names `DrawRightHalfCircle` does not look at all like drawing circle in traditional sense (square is indeed kind of circle with corners :) )

Comment: @Equalsk Yeah its 0 at the last iteration.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov You are the man, Im a bad programmer. satisfied?

Comment: Then that's why you get the error. On the last iteration of loop that means you're essentially calling `SetCursorXPosition(0 - 1);` which when then calls the equivalent of this `Console.CursorLeft = -1;` which is an out of bounds error.

Comment: @Equalsk if height = 4; I did a tracking table and after the last iteration the Xposition = 0  so it never calls SetX(0 - 1). Somehow it is ~~. But I will check it again. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra `SetCursorXPosition(currentCursorX - 1)` which make `currentCursorX`  negative on the last iteration of the second loop. Remove it substract one to loop cycle :

```
    for (int i = 0;i < height / 2;i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(printedCharacter);
        SetCursorXPosition(currentCursorX + 1);
    }

    // SetCursorXPosition(currentCursorX - 1); //  <-- Remove this 

    for (int i = 0;i < height / 2;i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(printedCharacter);
        SetCursorXPosition(currentCursorX - 1);
    }
```

Or eventually :

```
    for (int i = 0;i < height / 2;i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(printedCharacter);
        SetCursorXPosition(currentCursorX + 1);
    }

    SetCursorXPosition(currentCursorX - 1); 

    for (int i = 0;i < (height / 2) - 1;i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(printedCharacter);
        SetCursorXPosition(currentCursorX - 1);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But when I do that the algorithm not acts as I would like.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because on the last iteration of your loop the variable `currentCursorX` is set to `0`.

When the last iteration runs it calls this code:

```
SetCursorXPosition(currentCursorX - 1);
```

Which we have now learned is the same as:

```
SetCursorXPosition(0 - 1);
```

So when we get here:

```
Console.CursorLeft = currentCursorX;
```

We're trying to set the value to `-1` which is out of the bounds of the allowed values.

Try changing the line to this:

```
Console.CursorLeft = currentCursorX >= 0 ? currentCursorX : 0;
```

It basically says:

```
if (currentCursorX >= 0)
{
    Console.CursorLeft = currentCursorX;
}
else
{
    Console.CursorLeft = 0;
}
```